# Solution problem with JS task named Powers - functions and arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, function

I have problem with an easy task named **Powers** Here is the condition:

Numbers have Powers! They can transform themselves. One transformation is done by replacing:

each 0 - with the absolute difference of its neighboring numbers

all other even numbers - with the maximum of its neighboring numbers

each 1 - with the sum of its neighboring numbers

all other odd number - with the minimum of its neighboring numbers

The leftmost and rightmost numbers are neighbors.
A **K**-sum of a sequence is the sum of the numbers after **K** transformations of sequence. your task is to find the **K**-sum of given sequence

Input:
The input data is given as a parameter - an array of strings.
On the firs input line there will be the numbers **N** and **K** separated by a space. On the second input line are **N** number - the sequence.

Output:
The output should be printed on the console.
Output the **K**-sum of the given sequence

**Example**:
**Input**:
5 1
9 0 2 4 1

**Explanation**: 9 0 2 4 1 becomes 0 7 4 2 13

**Output**: 26 (sum of 0 7 4 2 13)

**Here is my code: **

```
'use strict';    
function slove(args) { 
    let k = Number(args[0].split(' ')[1]); 
    let numbers = args[1].split(' ').map(Number); 

    function transform(num, left, right) { 
        if (num === 0) {
            return Math.abs(left - right);
        } else if (num % 2 === 0) { 
            return Math.max(left, right);
        } else if (num === 1) {
            return left + right; 
        } else { 
            return Math.min(left, right); 
        }
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
        let currentTransformation = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < numbers.lenght; j++) { 
            let nextValue;

            if (j === 0) { 
                nextValue = transform(numbers[j], numbers[numbers.lenght - 1], numbers[1]);
            } else if (j === numbers.lenght - 1) { 
                transform(numbers[j], numbers[j - 1], numbers[0]);
            } else { 
                nextValue = transform(numbers[j], numbers[j - 1], numbers[j + 1]);             

            }

            currentTransformation[j] = nextValue;

        }
        numbers = currentTransformation;
    }

    let sum = 0;
    for (let num of numbers) {
        sum += num;
    }
    console.log(sum);
}

slove([ 
    '5 1',
    '9 0 2 4 1'
]);
```

So console.log(sum) need to return 26, but it return 0... I can't find where is the problem of my code.

Comment: First of all, you have a typo there, its `length`, not `lenght`. Also there is probably one forgotten like that breaks it (`numbers[j - 1], numbers[j + 1])`)

Comment: Thanks, I'm blind. The new console log i NaN...
For  (numbers[j - 1], numbers[j + 1])) - I forgot to delete because it was in comment.

Comment: You should use some IDE with syntax highlighting and/or some linter to catch those things :]

Comment: It's strange because I use VSC with extensions who catch most of errors...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code had 2 problems:

- you had a typo in length of an array -- its `length`, not `lenght`
- you forgot to save the last value in `if (j === numbers.length - 1)` block

```js
'use strict';

function solve(args) {
  let k = Number(args[0].split(' ')[1]);
  let numbers = args[1].split(' ').map(Number);

  function transform(num, left, right) {
    if (num === 0) {
      return Math.abs(left - right);
    } else if (num % 2 === 0) {
      return Math.max(left, right);
    } else if (num === 1) {
      return left + right;
    } else {
      return Math.min(left, right);
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < k; i++) {
    let currentTransformation = [];
    for (let j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
      let nextValue;

      if (j === 0) {
        nextValue = transform(numbers[j], numbers[numbers.length - 1], numbers[1]);
      } else if (j === numbers.length - 1) {
        nextValue = transform(numbers[j], numbers[j - 1], numbers[0]); // HERE
      } else {
        nextValue = transform(numbers[j], numbers[j - 1], numbers[j + 1]);
      }

      currentTransformation[j] = nextValue;
    }

    numbers = currentTransformation;
  }

  let sum = 0;
  for (let num of numbers) {
    sum += num;
  }
  console.log(sum);
}

solve([
  '5 1',
  '9 0 2 4 1',
]);
```

Comment: Thank you, I reed code ten+ times but I didn't saw it :)